# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS hangs with error: "hwmon1: Failed to get throttled ( -110)"

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi

I'm getting this under load on `Raspberry Pi 3B+` with fresh `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server 64-bit`, then the system hangs:

```
hwmon1: Failed to get throttled ( -110)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening or has any workaround?

Comment: I get exactly the same error when doing an rsync backup from a synology nas to a pi with external drives connected to it. From what I've found, the hwmon driver should be responsible to detect undervoltage. I get this error mesage together with `rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks: $0-...0: (33 ticks this GP) idle=efe/1/0x4000000000000002 softirq=78440/78441 fqs=2588`. I cannot really say if it is related to ubuntu server 20.04 or not since with the previous system I used to create samba shares and not use it as an rsync server. Have you tried other distors as well?

Comment: It indeed seems to be an ubuntu related bug (I can not narrow the cause enough to submit a bug report, though). I now installed raspbian and it seems to work just fine, with even higher transfer rates

Comment: I used raspbian before, and it was rock stable. The reason I'm trying Ubuntu is that I want 64-bit natively (no nspawn), as well as zfs module support out of the box. I was able to work around the issue by adding swap space (I use SanDisk Extreme Pro USB SSD thus it's not a problem), and it seems it doesn't hang anymore. The error is confusing though.

Comment: Also Ubuntu for 64-bit => zfs 
Some variables I hope I've eliminated:
  - Next error is mmc0/1 timeout. Had a swap *partition* but moved to dphys dynamic swap *file*. This hasn't changed the situation, in case the SD card was ocming under excessive stress using a swap
  - Undervoltage - I'm still getting occasional undervolts, but less frequently and using a PSU that formally outputs 2.4A on that line (2.5A is required maximum for the Pi 3B) and I have no lightning logo on the screen, so I'm more confident that this isn't likely to be it

May file a bug with launchpad and attach here

Comment: [Launchpad bug filed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1889637)